# Обработка событий мыши QGraphicsItem'а

Tags: qt

Пишу такой таймлайн:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый элемент это QGraphicsRectItem. Хочу даблкликом по элементу вызывать новый виджет (окно редактирования), узнал, что для этого необходимо переопределить функцию `void QGrapicsItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)`. Сделал `#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>`, создал экземпляр данного класа, что бы подать его на вход переопределенной функции.
Ну и сам вопрос, как мне переопределить эту функцию? Я если честно не понял, как это делается у элемента.
С собственным виджетом все понятно, он наследуется от QWidget, я в .h файле перегружаю функцию `void QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * event)`, в .cpp пишу реализацию и все работает, но где писать перегрузку функции для `QGraphicsItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и в случае с `QWidget` Вы должны не просто создать экземпляр `QGraphicsRectItem`, но и написать собственный класс, наследующийся от него. В этом случае у Вас будет возможность переопределять виртуальные защищённые методы в том числе и `QGraphicsItem`, поскольку последний является базовым для всех item'ов сцены. Очевидно, что экземпляры объектов для использования нужно уже будет создавать от Вашего нового класса.

```
class MyGraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem {
   public:
      //! Конструктор и прочее...

   protected:
      //! Событие двойного клика, реализуемое в cpp-файле.
      virtual void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};
```

Но также имеются ещё два способа получения и обработки событий на сцене.

Первый заключается в переопределении методов соответствующих событий непосредственно самого класса сцены. Конечно потребуется унаследовать `QGraphicsScene` в собственноручно созданном классе. В этом случае события для всех item'ов будут поступать в единый обработчик, а тот по различным критериям, которые Вы внесёте сами, будет формировать соответствующую логику исполнения.

Второй способ - установка фильтра событий.

```
my_scene->installSceneEventFilter(my_rect_item);
```

Ну а далее в собственном классе `my_scene`, унаследованном от `QGraphicsScene` переопределите виртуальный защищённый метод `sceneEvent()`.

```
class MyScene : public QGraphicsScene {
   public:
      //! Конструктор и прочее...

   protected:
      //! Обработчик отфильтрованных событий.
      virtual bool sceneEvent(QEvent *event);
};
```

Данный способ в отличие от первого позволяет таргетированно подходить к вопросу обработки событий, т.к. для каждого конкретного объекта класса item'а можно установить собственный фильтр. Однако не рекомендуется этим злоупотреблять, поскольку данный подход может значительно снизить производительность.

Comment: Спасибо) так ведь и думал что надо свой класс писать)